# sas macro for appending 24 tables

Tags: macros, sas, do-loops

Hi I need help to append 24 sas tables. I would like to write a macro that appends 24 tables. 
How do I create a do loop with the least amount of typing.
Thanks

```
proc sql;
create table master as
select * from table1
 union all
select * from table2
union all 
select * from table3;
quit;
```

Comment: I've linked you to a duplicate that does something similar to this.  There are many other questions that ask a similar thing - search `append` in particular, as `proc append` is more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I think you did not need a macro. Just type

```
data master;
set table1-table24;
run;
```